# Sort the parent model based on the child model / relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, model, eloquent

I have a model called `appointments`, each appointment has an `option_id` that is linked through a one to one relationship and the `option_id` can also be `null`. The option model has a property `datetime_start`. I want to sort the appointments based on the `option.datetime_start`.

Here is my code :

```
$appointments = $user->appointments()
->with(['option'
])
->get();
```

Edit :

Appointment model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Appointment extends Model
{
   /**
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
   */
   public function option()
   {
     return $this->hasOne(Option::class, 'id', 'option_id');
   }
}
```

Option model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Option extends Model
{
    protected     $fillable = ["appointment_id",
                               "datetime_start"
    ];

    public function appointment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Appointment::class, 'id','appointment_id');
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the code of the `Appointment` and `Option` models? It makes it easier to get your head around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort **Appointment** model by a column from related **Option** model, you need to add a **JOIN** to your query so that you can sort by related fields:

```
$appointments = $user->appointments()
  ->leftJoin('options', 'options.appointment_id', '=', 'appointments.id')
  ->orderBy('options.datetime_start', 'ASC')
  ->with(['option'])
  ->get();
```

This will give you all appointments, including those without **Option** - the ones without an **Option** and, hence, without **datetime_start**, will be all returned either at the beginning or the end of the result list, you'll need to check that. If you only want appointments with **Option**, replace **leftJoin()** with **join()**.

Answer (score 0):

`$appointments = Appointment::with(['option' =>  function ($query){ $query->orderBy('datetime_start', 'desc');  } ])->get();`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.